# Is it possible to populate sumif with dynamic range

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have the following data in Excel Worksheet A, which is a basic ledger of expenses:

The initial data looks like:

```
Week | Amount | Payee | Category
1    | 10.00  | John  | Cookies
1    | 12.00  | Bill  | Cookies
3    | 7.08   | Jason | Oranges
...
```

And I have assigned categories and calculate subtotals like this on another sheet using SUMIF :

```
Category | Total | Include?
Cookies  | 22.00 | True
Oranges  | 14.87 | 
...
```

I'm trying to get to a report that sums if that Include? boolean is set. By using SUMIF again, I can summarize by week:

```
    Total   IncludeSet?
1   100.06          
2   100.3   22.00       
3   80.07           
4   77.29
...
```

I know I could create an Extra column, and I could also try a SUMIFS and apply multiple criteria, but I'm up for learning how the pros would tackle this. At some point, I should just put this into MATLAB or a database.

Comment: So your second table is a week-by-week total for each category. I'm confused what the third table is doing exactly or how you're coming to the results displayed.

Comment: No, the second table is a total for the whole period. The third is a week-by-week total. Does that help?

Comment: I'm looking into using match . . .

Comment: and I got it working with something like this: =+INDEX(include_column,MATCH(I1,A2:A100,0)) in my SUMIF

Comment: I'd probably use a Pivot Table

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find a way to have a Pivot Table do it, but index and match worked well, with SUMIF. I had to create several extra columns as well.